# How to see variables defined in a Python interactive console in real time in Pydev, Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm new to Python (I used MATLAB before). What I want is showing all defined variables within an interactive console in real time, just like what MATLAB does.

My system: Windows 10 64-bits with python 3.6.6. My IDE is Eclipse photon 4.8.0 with Pydev 6.4.3

For example, variable **aaa** is defined in the **PyDev console [33]**, but the variable panel shows nothing. (please see the figure)

[image: Fig 1: No variable is shown in the variable panel]

But when I run the debugger and it holds at a breakpoint, variables are shown. So my question is: is there a way to show all variables defined in this interactive console all the time, not just during debugging? In short, I want an interface closed to MATLAB, so I can track variables constantly. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Matlab was created as a domain specific language, it comes it's own development environment geared towards numerical/scientific computing. Python is a general purpose programming language. Many professional developers use a simple text-editor and terminal as their development environment. If you want a development environment geared towards the use-case of Matlab, then consider something like Spyder (which mimic's RStudio). There are also Jupyter Notebooks, geared towards data analytics/data science workflows.

Comment: Actually, the PyDev interactive console has an option to couple it with the PyDev Debugger and this is actually used by many people to interactively inspect a program with variables as you'd do in Matlab (there was a bug in 6.4.3 though, but 6.4.4 is already released with a fix).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I guess part of the question is: "How do you couple the console with the Debugger so you can see the variables at all times?"

Comment: From the screenshots @shl7 already knows how to do this, but if anyone is interested, see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html (search for `Full Debug Support in Interactive Console` in that page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that... there was a bug in 6.4.3, which is fixed in 6.4.4 which prevented variables from showing properly, so, please upgrade and it should work.